Asp.net Identity logged in as WIN... after publishing to smarterasp.net
First time publishing a website. I'm using asp.net blazor (server side) with Identity. After publishing to smarterasp.net, and navigating to the website, it looks like I'm already logged in (clean database, so not possible of course). Because of this the site is not working, since I can't log out because the user doesn't exist.
I tested this with a clean project, to make sure it wasn't because of any changes I made:

I expect to be able to log in, and not already be logged in as a non existent user.

Your project should have test code that simulates user login, please check it out or share some of it.
